# i can't pass props to child component when requerying from server

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I request asynchronous data from the server and pass it through props to the child component, while registering it in a reactive variable. When I request the data again, I overwrite the reactive variable I pass to the child component, but the data doesn't change and nothing happens.
I use Nuxt3 last version

Index.vue:

```
<script setup> 
import { API_KEY, BASE_URL } from "@/constants/index";

const city = ref("Paris");
const weatherInfo = ref(null);

const getWeatherData = async () => {
  const { data } = await useFetch(
    `${BASE_URL}?q=${city.value}&appid=${API_KEY}`
  );
  weatherInfo.value = data;
};
<script>

<template>
<input
  @keyup.enter="getWeatherData"
  v-model="city"
  type="text"
  class="search"
/>
                  
<TheWeatherSummary :weatherInfo="weatherInfo" />
</template>
```

When I re-request data from the server, it is not updated in the child component

```
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  weatherInfo: {
    type: [Object, null],
    required: true,
  },
});

</script>

<template>
{{ weatherInfo }}
</template>
```

But this code works

```js
const getWeatherData = () => {
  const { data } = fetch(`${BASE_URL}?q=${city.value}&appid=${API_KEY}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => (weatherInfo.value = data))
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: But this code is work
const getWeatherData = () => {
  const { data } = fetch(
    `${BASE_URL}?q=${city.value}&appid=${API_KEY}`
  )
  .then((res)=> res.json())
  .then((data) => weatherInfo.value = data)
};

Why?)

Comment: I added your new code to your question. It's much easier to read there than in a comment.  What debugging did you do with the original code?  If you console.log ``${BASE_URL}?q=${city.value}&appid=${API_KEY}`` before the fetch, is the URL correct?  If you open your devtools to the network tab is any request made? If you console log the `data` after the fetch is there anything returned in that value?

Comment: Hi!
I checked the url before getting it and it is correct and in the network tab, the request goes away and the answer comes with the correct data
But I can't write data to a variable weatherInfo after request and I can’t pass data through props to a child component